# VB.et FileSystemWatcher Event Handler - Calls of Handler Repeats (Unwanted)

Tags: vb.net, events, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to log file activity in a directory with the FileSystemWatch class by adding the file to a custom class within a list, unfortunately, it seems that when copying a file or adding a new file to the target directory, it's running 4 times instead of once.

When adding a file to the directory, the AddressOf Sub will write 3 to 4 times instead of just once. I'm not sure why.

Here's the code snippet.

```
Public fileTypefilter As String = "*.xlsx"
Public DesDir As String = "C:\"
Public EventLog As List(Of FileEvent)
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim watchDir As String = DesDir
    Dim watch As New FileSystemWatcher(watchDir)
    Me.Text = "Monitoring " & watch.Path

    watch.IncludeSubdirectories = false
    watch.Filter = "*.xlsx"

    AddHandler watch.Changed, AddressOf watch_Changed

    watch.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub watch_Changed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs)

    Try
        EventLog.Add(New FileEvent(e.FullPath))
        Exit Sub
    Catch ex As NullReferenceException
        EventLog = New List(Of FileEvent)({New FileEvent(e.FullPath)})
        Exit Sub
    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: What is the point of those `Exit Sub` lines? There's no more code to be executed after either of them so why are they there?

Comment: I would strongly recommend getting rid of that code in the `Load` event handler and adding the `FileSystemWatcher` in the designer. You can then configure it in the Properties window. Just be aware that, if you do that, the `SynchronizingObject` property will be set to the form by default. If you don't know what the significance of that is, you should read the relevant documentation.

Comment: Why have that exception handler there when you could just create the list object where you declare the field?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback gents/lads. I'll look it over, the additional random "Exit Sub" statements were there to troubleshoot. As for the exception handler, well that's my way of ensuring a failsafe initialization of object/list, by no means is it perfect, but it works (until it breaks). I'll take a deeper look into the FileSystemWatcher doc to see if I missed anything.

Answer (score 2):

The `Changed` event handler is executed multiple times because multiple changes occur. As is ALWAYS the case, you should have read the relevant documentation for yourself first, which says:

> The change of a file or folder. The types of changes include: changes to size, attributes, security settings, last write, and last access time.

If you don't want to log each individual change then you need to filter them somehow. For instance, you might want to record the time a change occurred for a particular path and then not log a change if some minimum time has not elapsed since the last change for the same path.

There would also be the option of using a `HashSet` instead of a `List`. That could be configured to use an appropriate equality comparer and then you could call `Add` as many times as you like for the same path and it will only be added once. That would mean that, were a set of changes to occur later for the same path, those would not be logged. I'm not sure whether that would be an issue for you or not.